# PostgreSQL + XAMPP + yii2, Database Exception

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql, xampp

Соединил XAMPP, yii и postgreSQL. Создал элементарную бд, схему, 1 таблицу, в таблице 3 столбца: id_point (key,integer, это наш айдишник), title(text), point_xy(point). В таблице есть 1 строка. Создал с помощью gii Model для данной таблицы и CRUD. При попытке совершить запрос index.php?r=test/create всё в порядке, после заполнения полей вот таким образом:
=[image: заполнение полей]

Получаем ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ОШИБКА: отношение "test" не существует
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "test" ("id_point", "title", "point_xy") VALUES...
```

И ниже то же самое, в принципе:

```
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ОШИБКА: отношение "test" не существует
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "test" ("id_point", "title", "point_xy") VALUES...
```

Не подскажете, что за беда?

Comment: у вас в tableName указывается `test` вместо `id_point`